# Overlay an image onto a video feed (XAML)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, overlay

I am having a bit of difficulty overlaying an image onto a video feed. 
I am at best, a novice with programming so I apologise in advance if I don't explain anything clearly.

I am trying to overlay a transparent image onto a video feed which is currently coded like this

```
<Grid>
 *Other images are here that are not within the grid below*
    <Grid>
        <Image x:name = "Oval" Source = "Oval-outline-01.png" *other things like margin, size etc..* Canvas.ZIndex = "2">
        <controls:VideoViewerWPF x:Name = "videoViewer" *other things here*>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I have followed other examples whereby the Canvas.ZIndex is set to be higher. But this is still not working. I have previously had both the VideoViewer and Oval on two separate canvas (within the grid still) but still not had any luck with that either.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid>
 *Other images are here that are not within the grid below*
    <Grid>
        <controls:VideoViewerWPF x:Name = "videoViewer" *other things here*>
        <Image x:name = "Oval" Source = "Oval-outline-01.png" *other things like margin, size etc..* Canvas.ZIndex = "2">
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Put your **image** control after your **controls:VideoViewerWPF** so that it appears over your video feed.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this but no luck here :(

Comment: @Josh, can you please share a screenshot of your wpf window so that we can see how exactly you grid currently looks like?

Comment: Hi Sam, here is a dropbox link. https://www.dropbox.com/s/b0j5r6pldbhwvh9/screenshot.png?dl=0 as you can see the oval image (dotted lines) is looking like it is behind the videoviewer.

Comment: @Josh, After looking at your oval, I think that **image** might be coming over top of that **controls:VideoViewerWPF**, but you might not be able to see because that oval **image** is also of black bordered color and transparent fill color.

Please try changing the image to some color other than black.

Comment: when the program is running the camera provides a colour image (captured live) and the black oval image does not overlay

Answer (score 0):

My original answer was incorrect, as pointed out by Clemens below. Rather than deleting it (and thus also his suggestion as to what could be happening), I'll edit my answer to include his point.

He said that this may be a conflict between Win32, DirectX, and WPF rendering. Do you have any Win32 or DirectX components in your VideoViewerWPF?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970688(v=vs.100).aspx

I suggest replacing the controls:VideoViewerWPF with a native WPF control (button or something) and seeing whether the order is then as expected. If that's the case, it sounds like it could be the above issue.

Comment: This is not true, as the property is actually [`Panel.ZIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex(v=vs.110).aspx) in WPF, and hence works in every Panel, i.e. also in a Grid.

Comment: No, I guess OP is running into the ["airspace problem"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970688(v=vs.100).aspx). `Canvas.ZIndex` is the same property as `Panel.ZIndex`, you just can write it that way because Canvas is derived from Panel.

Comment: Edited the answer (I'll be happy to delete it if you want to put your suggestion as your own answer, don't want it to go missing in the ether though)

Comment: Replacing it with a button did actually make the image overlay the button, so i am guessing it is a problem as described in your post.